# How can the string be hyphened in a table when it is long and can possibly contain dashes

Tags: css

I am trying to fit a long string which can optionally contain dash(-).
When it contain dashes it should hyphen at these dashes.
I tried `word-break: break all;` but it does not break it at hyphens.
Is there any way to achieve my goal in a pure css?

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/5gyzv7cn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `break-word`, this will break the string at dashes if exists.

I've added:

```
td { 
word-break: break-word;
}
```

See JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hatufvy1/11/

Comment: Thanks for answering ! According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break  `break-word` is kind of deprecated, but it looks like `overflow-wrap: break-word` works